# How can i set timeout when i use VideoCapture to open a rtsp stream

Tags: rtsp, opencv3.0

I try to open a rtsp stream using the class VideoCapture's funtion `open`.
I want to set timeout,but i do not know how to do.

Answer (score 2):

I'm keeping this answer short, because I'm still looking for a better solution: there is a ffmpeg wrapper, which can be compiled to a ffmpeg dll file, which I guess replaces OpenCV's ffmpeg dll.
This ffmpeg wrapper is built in such a way, that a timeout can be set in milliseconds. I'll hopefully edit this when I have more information.

This is the wrapper, it's supposed to be easy to test in VS2012: [Git](https://github.com/peters/opencv.ffmpeg)

Comment: I answered this here, although not accepted as answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38365051/opencv-videocapture-timeout-on-open-or-constructor/40667970#40667970